# How can i cache a message | discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i create a bot discord and need a command **!edit [id] [new content]** so i made that:

```
if (MessageContent.startsWith('!edit ')) {
    if (autority >= 3) {
        //if false
        if (args.length < 3) {
            const modifErrorEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#eb9234')
            .setTitle('You made an error')
            .setDescription('To execute the command do: !edit <id> <Nouveau message>')
            m.channel.send(modifErrorEmbed)
        }
        //if correct
        if (args.length >= 3) {
            let id = args[1]
            let toRemove = '!edit  ' + id + ' '
            let toResend = MsgC.replace(toRemove, '')
            const toModif = m.channel.messages.cache.find((x) => (x.id === id))
            toModif.channel.messages.fetch(toModif.id)
            const modifModifierEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#eb9234')
            .setDescription(toResend)
            //we edit the message
            toModif.edit(modifModifierEmbed)
        
        
        }
    }
}
```

And like this i can verry well edit a message cached (sent after the last bot activation) but trying to do-it with a non-cached message it returns me an error:

```
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\draymone\Desktop\VSC\draymone\calypsiovalleybot\index.js:174:33)
    at Client.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\draymone\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\draymone\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\draymone\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\draymone\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\draymone\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\miloud\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\draymone\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20)
```

So please how can i fix that ?

Edit:
The solution was:

```
message.channel.messages.fetch(id).then(msg => {
msg.edit(modifModifierEmbed)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know for sure that this will fix it, but you should try directly fetching the message, instead of finding it then fetching it.

also, if you want the fetch() function to actually do something, you need to edit the variable, which also means you need to change toModif to either a `var` or `let`.

what I mean to say is that you would need to do is:

```
let toModif = m.channel.messages.cache.find((x) => (x.id === id))
toModif = toModif.channel.messages.fetch(toModif.id)
```

try the the first suggestion, and if that doesn't work then try the second one. i hope I understood your problem correctly :)

Comment: Hello, i tryed your 2 methods, but both failed
When i tried to fetch the message, when i did toModif.edit() it said me that the .edit() method can't be found
When i tried to find the message then fetch it, i, did message.channel.message.fetch(toModif.id) it told me that the .id stat can't be found

Comment: i found the solution, i just had to directly fetch, but not to ctock in a let ou a var but in a function .then() ^^

Comment: great! hope my answer helped :)